# Convert a pandas dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column with values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.

I want to convert this column to a binary column (0 or 1) based on a threshold, i.e. if the value is <= threshold it will become 0 and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Create boolean mask by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`) and then convert it to `integer`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[.4,0.5,.1]})

threshold = .2
df['new'] = df['col'].gt(threshold).astype(int)
print (df)
   col  new
0  0.4    1
1  0.5    1
2  0.1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.column = df.column > threshold
df.column.astype(int)
```

Answer (score -2):

I would create a helper column and then iterate through the rows and setting the value for each cell. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": a})
df["Helper"] = ""
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,"A"] <= 0.5:
        df.loc[i,"Helper"] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i,"Helper"] = 1
```

Which leads to this:

```
          A  Helper
0  0.114089       0
1  0.309759       0
2  0.158169       0
3  0.444199       0
4  0.645443       1
```

Comment: No, don't iterate! Use vectorization for this easy task

Comment: to add to @Quickbeam2k1, raw iteration in pandas should be avoided. If you do have to iterate, use `itertuples()`